# megane 2 2005 (55 plate UK) issues starting

Tags: ignition, megane

On a morning I get in the car and press the clutch and start the car using the button as normal but sometimes I can hear the car trying to turn over but nothing happens, then if I turn it off and try again it fires up as normal.
Also Im not sure if it has anything to do with it but when I am in idle for a long period of time the car has a progressive violent rhythmical jerk. I have used injector cleaner a few times but it still happens.
The car is a 1.4 16v petrol and idles at 750rpm (i dont know if thats normal) I have also just cleaned the throttle body and put the car through a service. It has around 65k on the clock.

Comment: Are you sure your car idles at 9500rpm? That's probably just a bit lower than a jet engine idles ... Maybe you meant *950rpm*?

Comment: God no! thats a typo its ~750 haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. To fix it I did the following:
New air filter
New spark plugs
New coil packs

But the thing that really helped is cleaned the throttle body with carb cleaner and a tooth brush.

While I had the engine open and the throttle body exposed I cleaned the air inlet manifold with carb cleaner too and checked the seals to make sure there were no leaks.

I also now need to change the engine mounts because they have prematurely worn due to the problem

Comment: I'm very happy you fixed the issue and also that you returned and let us know so.